# Firebase hosting 2 different versions when I use microsoft edge and google chrome

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, phaser-framework

so I am currently hosting a firebase website. When I use firebase deploy, I am able to get the link for the hosted website. When I look at it on Google Chrome, I realized that it was running a previous version that I was running. When I look at Microsoft edge however, it was running the current version that it was suppose to run. I decided to rollback to the same version in google chrome, but when I use the link on microsoft edge, it still shows me the version before the rollback.

[image: The version from microsoft edge]

[image: The version from google chrome]

At the moment, firebase hosting is at the rollback version, so it is suppose to look like the photo at the bottom, but in microsoft word, it still shows me the version before the rollback. Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: It sounds like Edge may be load the site from its cache. You'll want to look at how to force a refresh, and/or at implementing cache busting in your site.

Comment: if that is the case, can I assume its the same for google chrome?

Comment: The other thing to check out is service workers, which is a really cool way to allow web pages to work offline, but they make getting updates a bit weird.While your app is open, navigate to here in another tab: `chrome://inspect/#service-workers` and see if your app is there.  (Works in both Edge and Chrome)

Comment: based on the link that you sent, I do not see my app inside there